# Using an npm module written in JS in an Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ecmascript-6

Ok so I have a module in npm

you can install it running `npm i simple-avl-structure`

is pure JS code, so I want to use it in an Angular 2 app (in app.component.ts) . But I can't import it.

it says cannot find module

How can I use an npm module written in pure JS on Angular?

Comment: You need to build a type definition file: file.d.ts and install it under node_modules/@types/simple-avl-structure

Comment: Excuse me do you have any resource to check how to do that step by step?

Comment: Start with [this page](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html) onward. btw this handbook by Basarat is a MUST read AFAIC

Comment: Thanks @BrunoGrieder